# Problem with MAC OS installation with YAML

Tags: ros, yaml, rosinstall, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install ROS on Macbook (early 2009) running Mac OS X Leopard. I have run into problems regarding pyyaml which is required for installing ROS. Basically, I am able to launch python (v2.6) from the command line and import yaml, but when I run rosinstall (desktop-full) it gives me an import error saying no module named yaml. I have installed py26-yaml, libyaml using macports, but I still am not unable to install ROS. It seems that rosinstall is invoking the wrong version of python (I ran python_select for selecting 2.6 and currently that is the version that is actively used on my computer). So I would like some help in fixing it so that rosinstall invokes the correct version of python.

Thanks,
S.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9418/problem-with-mac-os-installation-with-yaml./) by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2011-03-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally fixed it. Just letting everyone know in case someone else has a similar problem. Basically, the problem with the pyyaml installation is, Mac OS X comes with a Python installation (2.5) which is located at
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/

Soft links for python, python-config, python2.5 etc for execs located in the above folder are available at /usr/bin.

Now Macports installs its own version of python (2.6 for ROS) which is located at
/opt/localLibrary/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions2.6/

Now, there are also multiple versions of easy_install the default one catering to python version 2.5. So if we do sudo easy_install -U rosinstall, rosinstall gets installed at /usr/local/bin and when launched references the original python version that came with Mac OS X. Making sure that the Macports bin path appears before /usr/bin doesnt fix this problem. So what I ended up doing is removing the soft links in /usr/bin for the original python installation. Then I used easy_install-2.6 to install rosinstall. Now, heres the tricky part, using this command installs rosinstall at /opt/localLibrary/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions2.6/bin/rosinstall and /opt/localLibrary/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions2.6/bin/roslocate. However, these are not included into the PATH variable by defualt. So, I just soft linked rosinstall and roslocate to /opt/local/bin and ran rostinstall. And everything works now! (well it seems to be installing).

From the [mailing list archives](http://code.ros.org/lurker/thread/20110314.162614.210d33f5.en.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2